# Calculate the derivative of the product of three functions $e^x\cdot \ln(x) \cdot \cot x$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I am trying to compute the derivative of

$$e^x\cdot \ln(x) \cdot \cot x$$

It's a product of three functions. I imagine I should first calculate the derivative of the first pair:

$$\color{red}{(e^x\cdot \ln(x))} \cdot \cot x$$

Which is, using the product rule:

$$\color{red}{\left(e^x\cdot \ln(x)+\frac{1}{x}\cdot e^x\right)} \cdot \cot x$$

Now I guess I should apply the product rule between these two things. But to do so I would need to calculate the derivative of the red part, and then...

... well, I *could*, but I suspect I am doing this in a very inefficient way. Perhaps because it's the first time I try to calculate the derivative of a triple product.

So my question is: is there a faster way to compute this derivative?

Comment: $(uvw)' = uvw'+uv'w+u'vw$.

Comment: @Kaster that looks pretty cool - how did you reach that conclusion?

Comment: $(uvw)'=(uv)'w+(uv)w'=u'vw+uv'w+uvw'$

Comment: Same way you did, but for more general case.
$$
(uvw)' = ((uv)w)' = (uv)w' + (uv)'w = uvw' + (uv' + u'v)w = uvw' + uv'w + u'vw
$$

Answer (score 1):

As Kaster points out in the comments above, $(uvw)' = uvw'+uv'w+u'vw$
We then set $u=e^x, \;u'=e^x, \;v=\ln(x), \;v'=\frac{1}{x}, \;w=\cot x, \;w'=-\csc^2 x$
Plugging these all in, we get
$$-e^x \ln(x) \csc^2(x) + \frac{e^x \cot x}{x} + e^x \ln(x) \cot x$$
$$=e^x\bigg[\frac{\cot x}{x} + \ln(x) \cot x -\ln(x) \csc^2(x)\bigg]$$

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a bit more sophisticated than necessary, but the derivative of the product of any finite number of functions is easily understood by **logarithmic differentiation**:  Let $$f(x) = \prod_{i=1}^n g_i(x).$$  Then define $h_i(x) = \log g_i(x)$, from which it follows that $$\log f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^n h_i(x),$$ and we immediately have $$\frac{d}{dx}\left[\log f(x)\right] = \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{dh_i(x)}{dx} = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{g_i'(x)}{g_i(x)}.$$  Consequently, $$f'(x) = \prod_{i=1}^n g_i(x) \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{g_i'(x)}{g_i(x)} = \sum_{i=1}^n g_i'(x) \prod_{j\ne i} g_j(x).$$  For $n = 3$, this gives us $$f' = g_1' g_2 g_3 + g_1 g_2' g_3 + g_1 g_2 g_3',$$ and the generalization should be quite natural to see.  The key insight is that taking the logarithm of a product makes it a sum; then the linearity of the differentiation operator becomes directly applicable.